Using CAN FD interface from WSL in QEMU image
I would like to use a CAN FD network interface from my host in QEMU.
Setup
I have a CAN FD network device (can0) in my WSL2, which I can use to communicate with the CAN2USB adapter connected to my Laptop. Everything works as intended, the app running on the host (in this case WSL2) communicates via socketcan.
Goal
I am also running a QEMU image in the WSL and would like to kinda "forward" the CAN FD network interface from WSL2 into the QEMU Image, so an application in QEMU would use the CAN FD interface (via socketcan) and the traffic would be then "forwarded" to the WSL2 and then to the CAN2USB adapter.
Any idea how to do it?
